# Best way to append a query string parameter to one URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, query-string

Looking for some advise on how best to approach a specific problem. I simply want one page of a wordpress website to have a static query parameter of `?locationid={locationid}` in the URL.

Much of my research on this website and wordpess.org relates to passing actual database values in query strings, and utilizing them to build the page. I know I can change the permalink structure, but that would be for all pages. I looked into using .htaccess, but that would be a re-direct and not the base URL, so there would be a delay. It is also not possible to add a query string to the pages permalink directly (when editing the page).

I really only just need this one page to have this static query string for another provider to utilize in their template, so how can I get the URL to be:

`https://website.com?locationid={locationid}`

This value won't change at run time and I don't need to populate this with any value.

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**

Early on I tried the below article mentioned by disinfor, and although it adds the query string parameter, it strips the `{}` from the string.

Comment: Hi imhvost, I am trying to create a page in Wordpress that will have a static query string added to it like ```https://website.com?locationid={locationid}```

Comment: I googled. I found: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169787/adding-a-query-string-to-only-one-page-url

Comment: Hi @disinfor - I tried that very early one, dropped it into the functions.php but it did not appear to have any effect on the URL including the { } - it stripped it from the URL

Comment: Curly brackets aren't allowed in URLs.  Based on your link, it looks like that is a placeholder for the actual numerical location id